# How can I initialize events with delegates that include runtime values?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I run into this issue while I was trying to assign a set of events with a set of delegate actions. If I use the function `AssignEventsManually()` the events trigger their assigned delegates with their contained information correctly (different numbers). When I use a loop to make those assignments, all buttons print the same value "B2".

It seems that the delegate itself is stored in the heap, but the iterating number `i` is in the stack and each delegate references the same item. How can I achieve assigning each delegate with its own instance of the iterator?

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DelegatesTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button[] bar;                

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bar = new Button[] { button1, button2, button3 };

            for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
            {                                
                bar[i].Click += delegate
                {                    
                    richTextBox1.Text = $"B{i}";
                };                               
            }

            //AssignEventsManually();
        }

        void AssignEventsManually()
        {            
            button1.Click += delegate
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = $"b{1}";
            };            
            button2.Click += delegate
            {                
                richTextBox1.Text = $"b{2}";
            };            
            button3.Click += delegate
            {                
                richTextBox1.Text = $"b{3}";
            };            
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems that the delegate itself is stored in the heap but the iterating number "i" is in the stack and each delegate references the same item. How can I achieve assigning each delegate with its own instance of the iterator?

`i` here is a "captured" variable as is on the heap in a context class. The context class is scoped the same as `i`, which is : for the duration of the loop

To fix it: create a snapshotted copy of `i` *inside* the loop.

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    int cpy = i;
    bar[i].Click += delegate
    {                    
        richTextBox1.Text = $"B{cpy}";
    };   
}
```

Or perhaps more efficiently:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    string txt = $"B{i}";
    bar[i].Click += delegate
    {                    
        richTextBox1.Text = txt;
    };
}
```

This works because the scope of the extra local is *inside* the loop, so: different capture context per loop iteration.